# Xpath selenium finding elements

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

How can I get class="aaa34" using selenium and xpath?

Comment: Hi. Please follow the guidelines : "summarize the problem, describe what you’ve tried and [...] show some code". Also please provide raw html code, not screenshot.

Comment: @E.Wiest I put my code but its  difficult to put html code.

Comment: If you can't post the html code, then please provide the url of the webpage you're working with. Add details too. What do you expect as output ? `//div[@class="jss1945"]` could be enough but it's hard to be sure without the data.

Comment: I told you, without the code, it will be hard to write a specific locator. What you can try, according to your screenshot and if the elements always have the same place : `//h1[starts-with(@class,"MuiTypography-root")]/following::div[descendant::*][last()]/div[starts-with(@class,"jss")]`.

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

```
client.Navigate().GoToUrl("*insert your URL here*");
IWEBELEMENT firstDiv =  client.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class,'__next')]"));

IWEBELEMENT secondDiv = firstDiv.FindElements(By.ClassName("jss1"));
```

This should do it. First I'm getting the parent `div` enclosing the `div` you want. That way I can get all the elements inside it, then filter what I want from it using the second `IWEBELEMENT` variable. Let me know if it doesn't work. There are other methods of selecting the `div` that could work. :)

Comment: I tried using the method with all the `/////`s but honestly I find that so confusing. Although it might be more accurate I still prefer my method, makes me go less mad when doing this stuff :D

Comment: Ok, so to get all elements of that class you'll want to use an `IList<IWebElement>`. So I think then you could use `IList<IWebElement> infoRequired =  client.FindElements(By.ClassName("jss1945"));`

I hope this works. Unfortunately I had to do a whole project with Selenium and webscraping and let me tell you with was a living hell. Sometimes selenium can be buggy to be honest and it didn't leave a good impression on me.

Comment: The point of the `ILIST` is like a normal `List` in coding. It will return to you a list of everything with that class in the webpage. However note that it's an `ILIST` for a reason. Getting the required value from the elements in the list is another thing which I could help you with if you need. :)

Comment: I still don't understand. On one page I have elements which I want with class jss1945 but on another with class jss1956. All this elements are in the same place but class name is different.

Comment: In that case then I think you'll have to use separate functions for each site then. So use what I've given you, but instead use a different class name in the part where im specifying the class name. It's tedious work I know, I've been there. But this is the best I can think of, a different function for each site which will gather the data but using the correct class names for the sites.

Answer (score 0):

if your class is unique and doesn't change with page loading, try following. I can't test it at my end though.

```
chrome.find_elements_by_class_name("jss1945")
```

Comment: my class differs by page